# Logic App HTTP connector: TrustFailure error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that calls a REST API via HTTPS.
The REST API is protected by a custom SSL certificat provided by a custom authority.
When I call it from the Logic App, I get a TrustFailure error, which is a normal situation.
But is it possible to add somewhere in Azure the trust chain in order to bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

It was confirmed by Microsoft that it is not possible to add my own authority certificates in the list of trusted authorities.

Comment: Although you can set up an Integration Service Environment that supports privately owned certificate authories. You need to invoke a particular PATCH REST API to it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-integration-service-environment-rest-api#add-custom-root-certificates